# why in xcode capabilities, there are two options for push/remote notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

I wonder why in xcode -capabilities, there are two options for remote/push notifications. 
one is called as "Push Notifications" and other one under "Background Modes" as "Remote Notifications"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is for remote notifications that wake up your app when it is in the background (so-called **silent notification**). They are not shown to the user, but your app gets a few seconds to react on them, e.g. for loading data in the background on server request.

See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html